# how can I assert minified javascript is equivalent to source

Tags: javascript, deep-learning, abstract-syntax-tree

I'm writing a webapp and I import a lot of minified JS libraries

Assuming they all minified using [terser](https://github.com/terser/terser/blob/master/lib/minify.js) which is used by js-minify

How can I assert (or score) the source (which I have) is equal to the minified version ?

- not all of them are signed and have sourceMappingURL

All I can think of is comparing AST trees using a greedy algorithm

Comment: Comparing AST trees may not work either, because minifiers can perform certain safe transformations on the source code (like turning a list of simple expression statements into a single comma expression).

Comment: I'm not sure there's actually a way to prove that an arbitrary transformation of a given text is the equivalent of the original without relying on the transformer itself.

Comment: Isn't that what unit/acceptance tests are for?

Comment: Also minify the source you want to compare? Assuming the exact same minifier was used, and it is deterministic, you should get the same result?

Comment: @jarmod "without relying on the transformer", what do you mean ?

Comment: @trincot minifier has a lot of options and I do not know which flags they set when they minified

Comment: I suppose for many of those options you could recognise which option was used by inspecting the minified code for certain patterns.

Comment: I mean that the only way in general to prove that the minified output came from a given reference source would be to minify the reference source i.e. use the same transformation. And that doesn't prove what you want to prove (that's it's an *accurate* representation of the original source).

Comment: @jarmod thank you, unfortunately, the developers does not always give the minification options/flags

Comment: Another option might be to write a very thorough unit test of the source code so that you can run that against the minified variant.

Comment: @jarmod most of the 3rd party libraries doesn't have unit tests or any way to test coverage